# How to get three equally high rows?

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework

I want an Ionic page/template consisting of three equally high rows - mening that they must scale with the screen size.

This is easy with columns using the  [Explicit Column Percentage Classnames](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid), but I can't find a similar tool for the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have 3 rows that are perfectly sized based on the viewport just use the `vh` unit in pure CSS.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div {
  background:red;
  height:33.33vh;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

1vh is always equal to 1% of the current viewport height, and [supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, but what if I just want it to be 33% of the parent? (I have a fixed footer in the bottom)

Comment: Just use 33% to size it to parent dimensions, and use `vh` units on the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using viewport height?

```css
div {height: 33.3vh;}
```

```html
<div style="background: grey"></div>
<div style="background: orange"></div>
<div style="background: yellow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you won't find this kind of feature for the rows.
As already suggested, add a height of:

div {height: 33.3vh;}

Although if you want to keep it responsive on all screen sizes/devices then I would suggest using

div {min-height: 33.3vh; overflow: hidden;
}

So then if anything is too large for this area then its not going to go outside of the div..